# How to add FailoverPartner to Connection String in Asp.Net Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I am trying to add a FailoverPartner to a connection string to an asp.net core application .

FailoverPartner works in connectionstrings in web.config files in asp.net eg

```
ConnectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxx.ad.xxxx.co.uk;Failover 
Partner=yyyyyy.ad.xxxx.co.uk;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; 
Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

I have added basic setup for sql server to the appsettings.json and appsettings.staging.json and that is working fine eg

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=XXXXXX.ad.XXXX.co.uk;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;Failover Partner=yyyyyy.ad.xxxx.co.uk"
  }
```

However adding the FailoverPartner to the end has no effect.

Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: What do  you mean by 'has no effect'.  What is the desired outcome and what is the error?

Comment: No effect means when the first server is not available it doesn't go to the Failover Partner.